# Power Bi Report server licence when you have Power Bi Premium

Tags: powerbi

By using Power Bi Premium licence (P1) can I install Power Bi Report server On Premise in the Server (capacity - CPU same as P1) which reside locally (within our organisation) without any additional cost?

Or with the Power Bi Premium licence (P1), do I need to install Power Bi Report server On Premise in Azure server only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/get-started#licensing-power-bi-report-server), with P1 you are licensed to install it locally.

> For Power BI Premium, Power BI Report Server is only included with P SKUs. It is not included with EM SKUs.